# How to materialize the result of a Promise within an async function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to run a query and return the result rows in a function:

```js
async function query(sql) {
  p(`sql: ${sql}`)

  let rows = await pool.query(sql)  // Notice the *await* here
  let r2 = rows.then( r => {
    debug(`nRows=${r.rows.length}`)
    return r.rows
  })
    .catch( err => {
      throw `Query [${sql}] failed: ${err}`
    })
    
  return rows
}
```

However the `rows` actually returns a `Promise` - instead of the actual results.  This is not making sense to me: then ***what is the *await* actually achieving in there*** ?  And then - how can the result be computed and returned by this function?

Comment: you need to know that `async` functions always returning promises. are you sure that `rows` is returning an promise or the function when you call it like `query(...)`?

Comment: How then can the `pool.query` results be materialized?

Comment: What does materialize means ?

Comment: you mean resolve? if you write `let rows = await pool.query()` yo should be able to see some result with `console.log(rows)`. Down there i see you return the rows like `return rows`. Because its inside an `async function` this will be wrapped in an resolved promise you can think of this `return Promise.resolve(rows)`. You will need to access the values like this later `query(...).then(rows => console.log(rows))`

Comment: It's another way to say "computed immediately".  I need the computation performed within the function and not postponed to the caller.

Comment: @Ifaruki I do not understand: if `console.log(rows)` is able to show results immediately then why would it re-wrap as a `Promise` ?  I do not want to invoke the `continuation`  `.then()` inside the caller.

Comment: `The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved promise automatically.` you can read here more https://javascript.info/async-await well the function itself is a promise so you are only able to get the results with `query.then(...)` or you make the function where your query should run also async so you need to write `await query(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3):

`async-await` is just syntactic sugar over the promises in javascript.

So using await is sufficient you don't have to again wait for the result in the then block

```
async function query(sql) {

try {
    let rows = await pool.query(sql) // Notice the *await* here
    // your logic to manipulate rows
    return rows;


} catch (err) {
    throw `Query [${sql}] failed: ${err}`
}

})
return rows
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try catch is a good idea to handle async await functions. This is an example with a promise function that resolves after 3 seconds, i hope this helps.

```js
function pool(sql) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved');
      }, 3000);
    });
}


async function query(sql) {
  try {
    console.log('calling . . .')
    let rows = await pool(sql);
    if(rows) {
      console.log(rows)
      return rows;
    }
    throw new Error('Request failed!');

  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

query('sql');
```

Comment: Can you make this *return* a value?  I need rows returned from the function and then not have to do a continuation in the main caller.  I am getting a bit desperate and thinking to send in a Holder and place the results in the Holder. That's ugly but I don't have anything else working presently.

Comment: check the value of rows, this async function returns the rows, you can handle that value inside the if block as you need.

Comment: ok i'll try it out in about 20 mins: working through something else

Comment: did not work. I ran in debugger and at the line `await pool.query(sql)` it jumps completely out of the `async function` with no data returned *and no error*.  Just drives me crazy

Comment: The `query('sql')` line returns a `Promise` and is not materialized. This answer is not a solution to the original question in its present form.